# what's the problem of my initialization map<string,LextType> lexname = {{"program",program}}?

Tags: c++, gnu

what's the problem of my initialization
it seems there is a problem

```
std::map<std::string,LexType> lexname_s = {{"PROGRAM",PROGRAM},
                                  { "TYPE" , TYPE},
                                  { "VAR" , VAR},
                                  {"PROCEDURE", PROCEDURE},
                                  {"BEGIN", BEGIN},
                                  {"END", END},
                                  {"ARRAY", ARRAY},
                                  {"OF", OF},
                                  {"RECORD",  RECORD},
                                  {"IF",  IF },
                                  {"THEN",  THEN },
                                  {"ELSE",  ELSE },
                                  {"FI",  FI },
                                  {"WHILE",  WHILE },
                                  {"DO",  DO },
                                  {"ENDWH",  ENDWH },
                                  {"READ",  READ },
                                  {"WRITE",  WRITE },
                                  {"RETURN",  RETURN },
                                  {"ID",  ID },
                                  {"INTC_VAL",  INTC_VAL },
                                  {"ASSIGN",  ASSIGN },
                                  {"EQ",  EQ },
                                  {"LT",  LT },
                                  {"PLUS",  PLUS },
                                  {"MINUS",  MINUS },
                                  {"TIMES",  TIMES },
                                  {"DIVIDE",  DIVIDE },
                                  {"LPAREN",  LPAREN },
                                  {"RPAREN",  RPAREN },
                                  {"DOT",  DOT },
                                  {"COLON",  COLON },
                                  {"SEMI",  SEMI },
                                  {"COMMA",  COMMA },
                                  {"LMIDPAREN",  LMIDPAREN },
                                  {"RMIDPAREN",  RMIDPAREN },
                                  {"UNDERRANGE",  UNDERRANGE },
                                  {"ENDFILE", EOF },
                                 {"ERROR", ERROR},
                                  };
```

error code

```
 error: could not convert ‘{{"PROGRAM", PROGRAM}, {"TYPE", TYPE}, {"VAR", VAR}, {"PROCEDURE", PROCEDURE}, {"BEGIN", BEGIN}, {"END", END}, {"ARRAY", ARRAY}, {"OF", OF}, {"RECORD", RECORD}, {"IF", IF}, {"THEN", THEN}, {"ELSE", ELSE}, {"FI", FI}, {"WHILE", WHILE}, {"DO", DO}, {"ENDWH", ENDWH}, {"READ", READ}, {"WRITE", WRITE}, {"RETURN", RETURN}, {"ID", ID}, {"INTC_VAL", INTC_VAL}, {"ASSIGN", ASSIGN}, {"EQ", EQ}, {"LT", LT}, {"PLUS", PLUS}, {"MINUS", MINUS}, {"TIMES", TIMES}, {"DIVIDE", DIVIDE}, {"LPAREN", LPAREN}, {"RPAREN", RPAREN}, {"DOT", DOT}, {"COLON", COLON}, {"SEMI", SEMI}, {"COMMA", COMMA}, {"LMIDPAREN", LMIDPAREN}, {"RMIDPAREN", RMIDPAREN}, {"UNDERRANGE", UNDERRANGE}, {"ENDFILE", -1}, {"ERROR", ERROR}}’ 
from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, LexType>’
           };
```

Comment: What is `LexType`?

Comment: Did you *really* need that huge list of initializers to demonstrate the problem, or would one of them be enough? Read about the [mcve].

Comment: @molbdnilo I would go with 2 or 3 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

`EOF` is a reserved a macro defined in stdio.h, so change this name

> EOF which expands to an integer constant expression, with type int and
> a negative value, that is returned by several functions to indicate
> end-of-file, that is, no more input from a stream. [ISO Standard]

Now If you paid attention to the error you will notice this   `{"ENDFILE", -1}` instead of `{"ENDFILE", EOF}`.

The `-1` is the value of the  `EOF` macro.

Comment: You're righthanks for that

Comment: @buting you are welcome and don't forget to edit your question and explain what is the datatype LexType in your question. I know it's enum but do it anyway